# WorkManager List<OneTimeWorkRequest> in series

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I am working on a file upload Worker that will send a potentially large list of
files. Currently I have it sending a single file with a progress observer for both the foreground and the notification. This seems to work well with a single file, once I enqueue multiple jobs or enqueue the manager with a list of work requests they all run in parallel. As per the [chaining documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work) this is working as expected. I need them to run in series however.

Reviewing the aforementioned docs it states to use `.beginWith().then()` etc. Attempting to implement this with a dynamic list of `then()` possibilities doesnt seem to be an option.

Is there another way to chain or process jobs in series? I dont care what order it chooses to upload from the job list so long as its a single job at a time.

Fragment.kt

```
val manager = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())
val requests = mutableListOf<OneTimeWorkRequest>()

files.forEachIndexed { index, it ->

    var data = Data.Builder()
    data.putString(FileUploadParams.FILEURI.param, it.uri.toString())
    
    ...
    val request = ( OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FileUploadWorker>()
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInputData(data.build())
        .build()
    )
    requests.add(request) // not needed since we are attempting to handle the chain inside this loop

    // We can try inside the loop since we are already here...
    
    if (index == 0) manager.beginWith(request)
    else manager.then(request) // <-- Unresolved reference
    
    manager.apply {
        if (index == 0) beginWith(request)
        else then(request) // <-- Unresolved reference
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably best to add it as [Unique Work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#unique-work) with a [Conflict Resolution Policy](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#conflict-resolution) of `Append`

As

> Unique work is a powerful concept that guarantees that you only have one instance of work with a particular name at a time

And Conflict Resolution Policy of `APPEND`

> APPEND the new work to the end of the existing work. This policy will cause your new work to be chained to the existing work, running after the existing work finishes.

Attempt an example using your code (not tested)

```
val manager = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())

files.forEachIndexed { index, it ->

    ...
    val request = ( OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FileUploadWorker>()
        .addTag("Upload") // Added to make tracking of all requests easier
        .setInputData(workDataOf(
           "FILENAME" to it
         ))

        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()
    )
    manager.enqueueUniqueWork(
           "upload",
           ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
           request)

}
```

Comment: This is not kicking off the job for some reason. If the list is 3 or more it jumps to the last job and runs that.

Comment: Just to test with APPEND_OR_REPLACE, this does run each job but its the same job each time it was enqueued. so the same file is uploaded X times.

Comment: Had the wrong ExistingWorkPolicy for Period not one time work and also `APPEND_OR_REPLACE` might be better. As for the same job I assumed you had used `setInputData` to send each job which file to upload and just missed it from your example.

Comment: Added and attempt setting input data to pass the filename (if `files` contains the filename, but what `files` contains was not defined in the example)

Comment: Yes, I am sending the file uri to the job and its creating the multipart request. I am finding different results using manage.enqueueUniqueWork() vs manager.beginUniqueWork().enqueue(). The latter seems to work unlike the former.

Comment: Continuing with this, using APPEND causes the work to never execute. Using APPEND_OR_REPLACE causes the work to execute in series HOWEVER the same exact job is ran for each enqueued.